# How can I stop my app from opening itself when I process text?

Tags: java, android

Whenever I click on my custom button to process some selected text, it takes me to the app screen. Any way to stop that?

AndroidManifest.xml:

```xml
<activity
    android:name=".ProcessTextActivity"
    android:label="CHANGE ME">
    <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

ProcessTextActivity.java:

```java
public class ProcessTextActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        CharSequence text = getIntent()
                .getCharSequenceExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT);


        System.out.println(text); // for testing
    }

}
```

EDIT:
Thanks to [CommonsWare's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60135788/how-can-i-stop-my-app-from-opening-itself-when-i-process-text?noredirect=1#comment106360931_60135788), I found a nice solution:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```xml
<activity
    android:name=".ProcessTextActivity"
    android:label="CHANGE ME"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"> <!-- new line -->
    <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT" />
         <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

ProcessTextActivity.java:

```java
public class ProcessTextActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        CharSequence text = getIntent()
                .getCharSequenceExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PROCESS_TEXT);


        System.out.println(text); // for testing

        finish() // new line
    }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the relevant code. Where is your custom button defined? Post the code of the on click listener

Comment: Sorry, I might not have been clear. The button is apart of the text selection popup under the kebab menu, like "Translate" for Google or "Search on Wiki" for Wikipedia. https://imgur.com/a/u5dpKmG

Comment: `ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT` is an activity `Intent`, so you need to use it with an `<activity>` as you are doing. That is unavoidable. What that activity does is up to you. So, for example, you could use `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"`, so the activity does not draw a UI.